# Use of particles for なにも in response to the question "What is in something?"

Tags: particle-を, particle-も

If the answer to the question, "What is in the pocket?" is "Nothing is in the pocket." is the topic marker が needed after "Nothing" (i.e., "なにもが ..." or just "なにも ...")?

Answer (score 4):

You'd say なにもない.  なにもがない is incorrect.

The particle も replaces the subject particle が, as in:

- 「なに**が**ある？ 」-- 「なに**も**ない。」 (×「なにもがない。」)
- 「なに**が**ありますか？ 」-- 「なに**も**ありません。」 (×「なにもがありません。」)
- 「[誰]{だれ}**が**いますか？」(Who's there?) -- 「誰**も**いません。」(No one's there.) (×「誰もがいません。」)
- cf. りんご**が**あります。 / りんご**も**あります。(×りんごもが～)

Answer (score 0):

"なにも" Should suffice as a response, but of course this would heavily rely on the context and flow of the conversation.
You could play it safer by saying "なにもない" which is a little more foolproof and natural sounding. Perhaps が　could be used in this more grammatically complete sense "なにもがない". Keep in mind how polite you wish to speak ^^

I Hope this has answered your question.
I know this is more of a comment, but I do not have enough rep to just comment. Sorry